# Problem with using a struct in a function and referencing it in an @IBAction (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I had to use a struct in my function to get the correct path to a Firestore document that I wanted to edit. But I have no clue how to reference this func in the @IBAction or how to solve the error that it gives me: `Cannot convert value of type 'TextPost.Type' to expected argument type 'TextPost'`

```
@IBAction func likeButton(_ sender: Any) {
        likeIt(with: TextPost)                          //Cannot convert value of type 'TextPost.Type' to expected argument type 'TextPost'
    }

func likeIt(with model: TextPost){
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let docRef = db.collection("posts").document(model.postID)

        if self.liky.tintColor == UIColor.red{
            docRef.updateData([
                "hasLiked": FieldValue.arrayRemove(["\(userID)"])
            ])
            print("removed like")
        }else{
            docRef.updateData([
                "hasLiked": FieldValue.arrayUnion(["\(userID)"])
            ])
            print("added like")
        }
    }
```

My struct is in an other ViewController file named: `popularViewController` and looks like this:

```
struct TextPost {
    let numberOfComments: Int
    let username: String
    let timestampName: String
    let userImageName: String
    let textName: String
    let postID: String
}
```

Comment: you need to pass in the reference of your struct , not the struct name 'TextPost' in your IBAction

Comment: how exactly would I reference my struct? @TejaNandamuri
Sorry if this is a dumb question, I am still learning

Comment: did you create a reference to this struct before or you want to pass in a new reference of the struct ?

Comment: I already created one in another ViewController, so I guess that I would have to do a new one? @TejaNandamuri . I also updated the question with some additional information

Answer (score 1):

Please note, I'm doing lots of guessing. Somewhere in your view controller is an instance of `TextPost`. It is likely named `textPost` with a lowercase t.

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    var textPost: TextPost // <-- instance of TextPost (with lowercase t)

    @IBAction func likeButton(_ sender: Any) {
        likeIt(with: textPost) // <-- lowercase t
    }

    func likeIt(with model: TextPost){
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let docRef = db.collection("posts").document(model.postID)

        if self.liky.tintColor == UIColor.red{
            docRef.updateData([
                "hasLiked": FieldValue.arrayRemove(["\(userID)"])
            ])
            print("removed like")
        }else{
            docRef.updateData([
                "hasLiked": FieldValue.arrayUnion(["\(userID)"])
            ])
            print("added like")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this and now it gives me ```Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value```in the IBAction.

Comment: I updated my question with some additional information @Jeffery Thomas

Comment: @JanSwoboda How is the view is setup? How do you display things like `textName` or `numberOfComments` in your view?

Answer (score 0):

You are only declaring a variable "var textPost: TextPost". It's not yet allocated with any values. Hence it is throwing exception as is founds nil. Try assigning some values to it. Try like below:

var textPost: TextPost = TextPost.init(numberOfComments: 3, username: check, timestampName: check, userImageName: check, textName: check, postID: check)

Comment: Alright, but that would defeat the purpose of my code, to get the unique postID of every post to check if the user has liked it or not @user3345698

Comment: Ok. understood.. Then call the likeIt function only if you have value in that variable.. This error is happening because it is called with null value. Or change the function likeIt to accept optional value well. Then make the required checks inside that function